# A problem with creating a channel with Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

UPD: ISSUE RESOLVED THANKS TO @Tenclea . Problem was with channel creation function. THe correct usage is `message.guild.channels.create();`!

I've faced an issue regarding creating a text channel on executing command `!w`. The issue is that when I try `let USER = (message.mentions.members.first()).username;` it executes undefined and also `message.member.send()` doesn't work as intended.

P.S. [info about the code] the command not only creates a new text channel available only to the executor of the command and mentioned user, but also sends a welcoming message to the other channel (`message.channel.send();`) as well as a DM to mentioned user (`return message.member.send();`).

Here's the code. Thanks in advance!

```js
else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}w`)) {
  if (message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
    let random = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
    var channelname = random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    let USER = (message.mentions.members.first()).username;
    const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('722892241416355940');
    (async() => {
      message.delete();
      message.guild.createChannel(`${channelname} ${USER}`, {
        type: 'text',
        parent: '550691726587723786',
        permissionOverwrites: [{
          id: message.guild.id,
          deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
        }, {
          id: message.member.id,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
        }, {
          id: message.author.id,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES']
        }]
      });
      message.channel.send(`:wave: we got a newcomer -  <@${message.member.id}> ! Welcome!`);
      return message.member.send({
        embed: {
          color: 1437003,
          title: ":wave:  Hello!",
          description: `Welcome to the server!`,
          footer: {
            text: "Issue !help for more instructions"
          }
        }
      })
    });
  } else {
    return message.reply(' something went wrong!')
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your member variable with:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Then check if the user exists:

```js
if (!member) return message.reply('Could not find this member.');
```

And then, your whole `async` function should look like this:

```js
(async() => {
      message.delete();
      message.guild.channels.create(`${channelname} ${member.user.username}`, {
        type: 'text',
        parent: '550691726587723786',
        permissionOverwrites: [{
          id: message.member.id,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
        }, {
          id: member.user.id,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES']
        }]
      });
      message.channel.send(`:wave: we got a newcomer -  <@${message.member.id}> ! Welcome!`);
      return member.send({
        embed: {
          color: 1437003,
          title: ":wave:  Hello!",
          description: `Welcome to the server!`,
          footer: {
            text: "Issue !help for more instructions"
          }
        }
      })
    });
```

I hope that it will help you :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip! Oddly enough this solution doesn't work. More than that the command just stopped working on execution leaving no errors or logs! here's the screenshot: https://ibb.co/Wkm5sbb

Comment: Not even a message in the chat ?

Comment: Weird.. do you mind providing a link to your full file ?

Comment: of course! here it is: https://pastebin.com/qc0LiDxv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216209/discussion-between-joshjohnson-and-tenclea).